# iodbctest works but Excel says "No ODBC driver installed"

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, odbc

I'm trying to connect Excel in OS X to a Vertica database and I have their ODBC driver working with iodbctest but when I boot Excel and click on Database I get "No ODBC driver installed"

What are the next debugging steps?

Answer (score 2):

You *probably* just need to install the [full iODBC SDK](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X), which includes the iODBC Frameworks against which Microsoft Excel and its helper Microsoft Query were built.  (iODBC is a freely licensed, open source project.)

For best results, use the **OpenLink ODBC Administrator.app** (`/Applications/Utilities/`) or **iODBC Administrator.app** (`/Applications/iODBC/`) to configure your DSN(s).

If you have manually configured things to this point, note that for use with Excel, System DSNs should be stored in `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`, and User DSNs should be in `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`; drivers should be registered in `/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini`.

Comment: Thanks TallTed, I had a similar issue but connecting to a postgresql database from Excel. Installing the iODB SDK helped me to resolve it.